# Proof of Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm learning complex analysis and I'm using Ahlfor's book as reference, in which Ahlfors proved the Cauchy-Riemann eq. by differentiating the complex function $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ as shown below:

[Proof taken from Ahlfors's book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2zmB.png)

However, I couldn't stop myself from wondering what if the function is indifferentiable along other directions apart from $Ox$ and $Oiy$.

Then I managed to prove it based on my understanding:

I want to prove that $f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{\Delta f(z)}{\Delta z}=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{u(z+\Delta z)+iv(z+\Delta z) - (u(z)+iv(z))}{\Delta z}$ is equal in all directions. So suppose that $\Delta z=\Delta x+i\Delta y$ with $\Delta x = k\Delta iy\,(k\in \Bbb R,\, k\neq 0)$.

We have:

$$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{\Delta u+i\Delta v}{\Delta x+i\Delta y}(1)$$

Substitute $\Delta x = k\Delta iy$ into (1):
$$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta y \to 0}\frac{\Delta u+i\Delta v}{(k+1)i\Delta y}=\frac{1}{k+1}(-\frac{i\delta u}{\delta y}+\frac{\delta v}{\delta y})(2)$$

Substitute $i\Delta y = \frac{1}{k}\Delta x$ into (1):
$$f'(z)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta u+i\Delta v}{({1\over k}+1)\Delta x}=\frac{k}{k+1}(\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}+\frac{i\delta v}{\delta x})(3)$$

For $f(z)$ to be analytic (2) must be equal to (3):

$$\frac{1}{k+1}(-\frac{i\delta u}{\delta y}+\frac{\delta v}{\delta y})=\frac{k}{k+1}(\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}+\frac{i\delta v}{\delta x})$$
$$\implies -\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}=k\frac{\delta v}{\delta x}\,\,\,\,;\,\,\,\,k\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}=\frac{\delta v}{\delta y}\,(*)$$
So my question is is my proof correct? I recognized that in (2) and (3) $f'(z)$ is undefined at $k=-1$ and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Question: $x$ is real. How can $\Delta x$ be an imaginary number (as you have taken $\Delta x = k\Delta iy$)? What is the path specifically?

Comment: Just pick any real basis of $\mathbb{C}$ and differentiate in those coordinates (i.e., write any $z = c_1z_1+c_2z_2$ for $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$ a real basis $\{z_1,z_2\}$ of $\mathbb{C}$). However, it suffices to check using just the standard basis because of the change of basis formula and the chain rule.